# Administer multiple SQL servers - possibilites

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to run queries against multiple SQL servers.

How this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it [can be done](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964743.aspx), but it would help if you can clarify if you want to do this from an application, from sqlcmd or PowerShell scripts or some other way.

Comment: It will also help if you tell more about the nature of the queiries: select, update, admin...

Comment: Also, what version and edition of SQL Server?  Some later versions have this capability built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest that you will come is Multi Server Administration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213819(v=sql.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191305.aspx

This will allow you to schedule jobs, which can run queries against multiple servers.

Another concept that might apply is Federated Servers.  This allows you to split data between servers and balance the work load.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187075(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

SQL introduced a new feature call "Central Management Servers (CMS)" which allows you to administer multiple servers.

For more details, please check this out

```
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1767/execute-sql-server-query-on-multiple-servers-at-the-same-time/
```